# OSX 10.9.4 ruby -version error

Tags: ruby, osx-mavericks

Not sure what happen do my ruby install

`$ ruby -version
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-12-22 patchlevel 375) [i686-darwin13.3.0]
-e:1: undefined local variable or method rsion' for main:Object (NameError)`

Comment: you're using java's version call. `ruby -h`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can string multiple parameters together when you run Ruby. In this case, -v is being interpreted as 'version' where as the 'e' is being interpreted as -e, which from the man page:

> Specifies script from command-line while telling Ruby not to search the rest of the arguments for a script file name.

Ruby is then trying to parse the remainder ('rsion') as an argument to the -e.  What you want it either:

```
ruby -v
```

or

```
ruby --version
```